# Azure DevOps XML Transformation During Release Not Working

Tags: c#, xml, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to configure our pipeline to allow one build to be used for multiple environments without having to create separate builds. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts), it seems like it is possible, as it says:

> - You can use this technique to create a default package and deploy it to multiple stages.

I named my stage as my environment (preview), and I created a web.config file for that environment (web.preview.config) file. All my environment configuration files in the same path as Web.Config file.

The logs say transformation was complete:

> 2018-11-17T00:26:52.0383966Z [command]D:\a_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.4.13\ctt\ctt.exe s:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.config t:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.Release.config d:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.config pw i
>   2018-11-17T00:26:52.4335280Z [command]D:\a_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.4.13\ctt\ctt.exe s:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.config t:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.Preview.config d:D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_06958915987488234\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp\Microsoft.Xbox.Mvp.Api\obj\Preview\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Web.config pw i
>   2018-11-17T00:26:52.5443873Z XML Transformations applied successfully

I can see that it first transformed to release and then it applied preview as the doc says (release then environment). However, although it says XML Transformations applied successfully, when I check the config variables, they are not changed. The only way I could make the transformation work was to define the buildConfiguration variable when I queue a new build, which blocks me from using the same build for different environments.

When I was researching, I found this from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260243/transform-web-config-for-azure-website-deployment-for-each-release-environment?rq=1):

> Web.config is transformed during the build process, if you generate the deployment package from "Build" and then deploy it in "Release", then you cannot transform it before deployment.

But the doc said I can use one default package for multiple stages...Does that still mean I have to create separate build for each environment? Is XML transformation not what I should be looking at for the scenario I wanna solve?

Thank you in advance!

++ Edit:

Release Settings:
[image: ReleaseSettings]

Release steps (I think? I have a strong feeling that this is what you are looking for...): 
[image: ReleaseSteps]

Comment: How are you checking your config variables?

Comment: On Azure app service, i can see what current variables are from remote execution console.

Comment: The scenario you described should work. Basically you include your base web.config and all web.{stage}.config files to your artefacts from build and then apply transformation during the release. Can you check what is inside your artefacts and maybe include screenshots of your release step and settings?

Comment: @JleruOHeP I just looked up our artifacts but I don't see anything transformation related except setParameters.xml which I'm doing nothing about. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be seeing something else or this is correct. I can include screenshots of our release steps and settings.Thanks!

Comment: Images looking good, inside your artefacts (your .zip file) there supposed to be at least 3 xmls: Web.config , Web.Release.config , Web.Preview.config. Can you confirm that all of those have the right settings?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254446/how-to-include-my-config-transformation-files-in-the-web-deploy-zip

Answer (score 17):

1) Make sure you transform works. Test it 
[here.](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/)

2) Ensure in your VS project that you are including the transform file, Web.Preview.config, and copying to output dir.

3) Disable the config transform during the build, you just need to add argument /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False in MSBuild Arguments section of your Build task. You also need to add /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False if you want to update the connection string during the release.  This will use the Web.Preview.config to "transform" the web.config.

4) Double check that in your release for the IIS Web App Deploy task under File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options you have XML transformation checked.

Comment: The bit about disabling the web config transformation on the build was helpful to me, but rather harder to find than I expected.

Comment: Remove `DependentUpon` on the transform files in project file might also help

Comment: ... and `/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False` needs to be set too so the `connectionStrings` section gets transformed

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers I found on the internet worked for me on their own for my build and release pipeline. The `web.config` I got from the release pipeline was always pointing to the non transformed values.

After a few hours pulling my hair I got it to work though.

### Some short info about my setup

I want to be able to deploy on all environments with just one build and one release pipeline.

My setup:

- One build pipeline that builds all of our standard branches (*test*,
  *release*, *master*).
- One release pipeline that has different stages
  depending on branch that started the release.

[image]
Our test stage releases the test branch on our test server.
Stage/Production comes from the same release branch but have their own transform files.

### Solution

I followed some of the [guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmltransform) and set up my `web.<environment_name>.config` to match the release stage names.

I did not need to remove the `<Dependent Upon>` rows from my `.csproj` for each transform. Instead all I did was set the property *Build Action* of each transform to **Content** as shown by the image bellow.

[image: Azure DevOps Release Pipeline map]

I then added these commands to the build pipeline's Build Solution -> MSBuild Arguments:

- `/p:MarkWebConfigAssistFilesAsExclude=false`
- `/p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=false`
- `/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False`

The build now does not try to transform the `.config` on it's own and also does not exclude the transform files from the artifact, allowing the release pipeline to do the transformation instead. Also, keeping the `<Dependent On>` for the transform files lets us have a "cleaner" look inside our code editors.

Comment: This Solution also works for those who are deploying to hosting environment other than Azure. For Azure Deploy task, you simply check on xml transformation option, but that option is not available for other types of deployments. It helped me, thanks bro!

Comment: I use the above to deploy to an Windows Server on an IIS. I also use the XML transformation option but that did not solve my problems before I did everything else described above.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this working so I could have one build with deployment to multiple environments. This is what I did.

In the code, I set each `Web.<Environment>.config` property to `Build Action = "Content"`. I also set all mine to `Copy to Output Directory = "Copy Always"`. I also unloaded the project and edit the `csproj` file, then removed the `<DependendUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>` lines. This dumps all your `web.configs` to the root (no file nesting).

In the build, I set pipeline variable `BuildConfiguration = "Release"`. I don't have a `Web.Release.config` in my project.

In the release, I named the deployment stage after the environment (in my case, `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`). In all stages, on the Azure deployment task, I checked the XML transform checkbox.

In Azure, I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to the naming of the staging environment, in my case, `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`).

Comment: Just wanted to add this with all Joe Wilson said.
I had a web.config web.Release.config and web.Debug.config. All came by default with asp.net. I set my devops build as "Release" and did the xml transformation and failed.
However, if i do a debug build then it passes. So somehow it messed up w/ the "Release build with the web.Release.config". So I took Wilson's advice and change my web.Release.config to web.Production.config and named my release stage name as "Production". So long story short just name whatever but don't name it "web.Release.config"

Answer (score 2):

I just got this working as well.  My issue was actually at the Visual Studio Solution level.  I had the MVC project pointed to a different Configuration than the others.  So always double check the configs!

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted since it was the fix for me.