# Azure Pipeline XML Transformation option <EnvironmentName> variable?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

Sorry to ask this question but I'm for several days now working on this XML transformation system. You can check here: [Azure Pipeline File Transformation is not working. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55945554/196526)

In IIS Web App Deploy task there is an option called XML Transformation with message:

> The config transforms will be run for *.Release.config and
>   *.<EnvironmentName>.config on the *.config file. Config transforms will be run prior to the Variable Substitution. XML transformations
>   are supported only for Windows platform.

What is and how can I set this `<EnvironmentName>`? Is it the name of my phase? Is it a name I can set in variables? Is it a name I can set to my phase 1 than change to my phase 2?

Comment: I think is the name of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnvironmentName is the name of stage in your release pipeline. Details can be find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-transformation-notes).