# DevOps: Build Solution task not copying Web.config file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-config, web.config-transform

In our DevOps build pipeline, the Build Solution task is properly transforming the "web.base.config" file to "web.config" file, however the artifact file contains only the "web.base.config" and not "web.config".

Our visual studio project file / config file setup looks like this:

```
…
    <Content Include="Web.Base.config" />
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.Base.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Dev.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.Base.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.QA.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.Base.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
…
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == ''">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

The msbuild arguments for the Build Solution task look like this:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

In the build log file, I can see the transformation taking place successfully.

```
2019-01-31T21:13:32.1186618Z BeforeBuild:
2019-01-31T21:13:32.1186784Z   Transforming Source File: Web.Base.config
2019-01-31T21:13:32.2198256Z     Applying Transform File: Web.Dev.config
2019-01-31T21:13:32.4750975Z     Output File: Web.config
2019-01-31T21:13:32.5213915Z   Transformation succeeded
```

What do I need to do to get the transformed "Web.config" file to the artifact staging folder?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53856111/5588197

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved - the Web.config file itself had to be part of the CSPROJ file, which it wasn't.  Once I added it to the project file, I saw it published/pushed to the web site.  I added it to the proj file like this:

```
...
<Content Include="Web.config" />
<Content Include="Web.Base.config" />
<None Include="Web.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.Base.config</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
...
```