# Config Transforms for Console application are not deployed to Azure App Service using Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

When I attempt to deploy my console application to our stage environment, the config transforms are not being applied correctly. I'm aware that the final format needs to be {ConsoleProjectName}.exe.config, and the logs for the release pipeline appear to be showing me the expected results, but when I look at the config file for the Web Job (and when the job is executed), it's using the Release config rather than staging config.

In the project, I have two app config files for the environments I want to deploy to:

```
App.Release.config
App.Stage.Config
```

In my csproj file, I've set it up to copy these files to the expected output name (LegendMaintenance.exe.{Environment}.config):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\App.Stage.Config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\$(AssemblyName).exe.Stage.config">
    </Copy>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\App.Release.Config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\$(AssemblyName).exe.Release.config">
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

When I build this in Azure DevOps, I can see the files are placed correctly from the artifacts it creates. I've also confirmed the content of these files are correct:

[image: Config file transforms]

When I create my release build, I have the Transform XML parameters checked:

[image: XML Transformations checkbox in Azure DevOps]

And when I check the build log, it looks like everything is being transformed as expected:

```
2020-04-29T22:21:01.7754752Z [command]D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX\4.163.5\ctt\ctt.exe s:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config t:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.Release.config d:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config pw i verbose
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9071810Z Start tranformation to 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9072649Z Source file: 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9073219Z Transform  file: 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.Release.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9073943Z Transformation task is using encoding 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding'. Change encoding in source file, or use the 'encoding' parameter if you want to change encoding.
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9074503Z Executing Replace (transform line 3, 21)
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9074838Z on /configuration/connectionStrings
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9075309Z Applying to 'connectionStrings' element (no source line info)
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9075676Z Replaced 'connectionStrings' element
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9076209Z Done executing Replace
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9076565Z Executing Replace (transform line 7, 46)
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9076941Z on /configuration/appSettings/add[@key='Environment']
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9077340Z Applying to 'add' element (no source line info)
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9077940Z Replaced 'add' element
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9078245Z Done executing Replace
...
2020-04-29T22:21:01.9114114Z [command]D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX\4.163.5\ctt\ctt.exe s:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config t:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.Stage.config d:D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config pw i verbose
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0382404Z Start tranformation to 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0383056Z Source file: 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0383676Z Transform  file: 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\LegendMaintenance.exe.Stage.config'.
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0384223Z Transformation task is using encoding 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding'. Change encoding in source file, or use the 'encoding' parameter if you want to change encoding.
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0384646Z Executing Replace (transform line 3, 21)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0384907Z on /configuration/connectionStrings
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0385184Z Applying to 'connectionStrings' element (no source line info)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0385609Z Replaced 'connectionStrings' element
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0385828Z Done executing Replace
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0386197Z Executing Replace (transform line 7, 44)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0386478Z on /configuration/appSettings/add[@key='Environment']
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0386776Z Applying to 'add' element (no source line info)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0387012Z Replaced 'add' element
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0387299Z Done executing Replace
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0388971Z Executing Replace (transform line 12, 83)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0389270Z on /configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0389552Z Applying to 'smtp' element (no source line info)
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0389837Z Replaced 'smtp' element
2020-04-29T22:21:02.0390034Z Done executing Replace
...
2020-04-29T22:21:09.0855271Z Info: Updating file (legendjobboard\app_data\jobs\triggered\JobBoardWebConsole\LegendMaintenance.exe.config).
```

However, when I check the LegendMaintenance.exe.config file in my app service, it's showing the release values rather than the staging values.

One interesting thing to note is that the app.config itself appears to be transformed as expected (it uses the Staging configuration). I could probably work around it by renaming that file somehow, but I don't understand why it's not working as-is, especially since the Azure DevOps logs seem to indicate it is.

Also note that this process works fine for our website deployment task, it's just the Console Project/Web Job that has the issue.

What am I missing? Is there any way to troubleshoot the web deployment process in Azure DevOps? Or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: Here are my configurations from the artifacts I downloaded from the build output (values are censored since they're basically all sensitive):

[LegendMaintenance.exe.config](https://gist.github.com/lynx44/5360767d80c5b57d3100aaac0c344faf)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="JobBoardDbConnection"
      connectionString="Server=tcp:aaa.database.windows.net,1433;Database=aaa;User ID=aaa@aaa;Password=aaa;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="production"/>
    <add key="MaxWidth" value="3000" />
    <add key="MaxHeight" value="3000" />
    <add key="ResumeCache" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\"/>
    <add key="ResumeFiles" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="IndeedXmlFileLocation" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa"/>
    <add key="SnagAJobXmlFileLocation" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa"/>
    <add key="ZipRecruiterXmlFileLocation" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa"/>
    <add key="IndustryXmlFileLocation" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa"/>
    <add key="DefaultXmlPublisher" value="aaa" />
    <add key="DefaultXmlPublisherUrl" value="http://aaa" />
    <add key="ArenaIOApiUrl" value="https://aaa"/>
    <add key="ArenaIOApiUserName" value="aaa"/>
    <add key="ArenaIOApiPassword" value="aaa"/>
    <add key="ArenaExceptionsEmail" value="aaa@aaa.com,aaa@aaa.com" />
    <add key="JobFeedDirectory" value="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa"/>
    <add key="IndeedApplyApiToken" value="aaa"/>
    <add key="IndeedApplySecretKey" value="aaa"/>
    <add key="IndeedApplyPostUrl" value="https://aaa"/>
    <add key="TwilioAccountSid" value="aaa" />
    <add key="TwilioAuthToken" value="aaa" />
    <add key="TwilioMessagingServiceSid" value="aaa" />
    <add key="FacebookCompanyId" value="aaa" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RazorEngine" publicKeyToken="9ee697374c7e744a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.1.0" newVersion="3.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SimpleInjector" publicKeyToken="984cb50dea722e99" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="aaa@aaa.com">
        <network host="smtp.aaa.net" port="587" userName="aaa" password="aaa"
          enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="JobBoard.Infrastructure.Logging" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
      <target name="LogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa.txt"
        layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | Message: ${message}"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

[LegendMaintenance.exe.Release.config](https://gist.github.com/lynx44/3765d6afea62f1c9e241787558174c88)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="JobBoardDbConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxx;User ID=xxx@xxx;Password=xxx;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="Environment" value="production" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="ResumeCache" value="D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="ResumeFiles" value="D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndeedXmlFileLocation" value="D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="SnagAJobXmlFileLocation" value="D:\xx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="ZipRecruiterXmlFileLocation" value="D:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndustryXmlFileLocation" value="D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="ArenaIOApiUrl" value="https://xxxx.com/xxx-xxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"  />
    <add key="ArenaIOApiUserName" value="xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"  />
    <add key="ArenaIOApiPassword" value="xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"  />
    <add key="ArenaSecurityKey" value="xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"  />
    <add key="JobFeedDirectory" value="D:\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndeedApplyApiToken" value="xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndeedApplySecretKey" value="xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndeedApplyPostUrl" value="https://xxxx" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="xxx@xxx.com" xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <network host="smtp.xxxx.net"
                     port="587"
                     userName="xxxx"
                     password="xxxxxxxx"
                     enableSsl="true"/>
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <targets xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <target name="LogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.txt" layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | Message: ${message}" />
        </targets>
    </nlog>
</configuration>
```

[LegendMaintenance.exe.Stage.config](https://gist.github.com/lynx44/e4706b0634f366729159376bbad6f13e)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="JobBoardDbConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:yyy.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yyy;User ID=yyy@yyy;Password=yyy;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="staging" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="IndeedApplyPostUrl" value="https://yyyy" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yyy@yyy.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="D:\yyy\yyy\yyy\yyy\yyy"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is stage name where this issue appears?

Comment: It's named "Stage"

Comment: Here is a  [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643303/azure-devops-xml-transformation-during-release-not-working) with similar issue you can refer to .

Comment: Thanks HughLin-MSFT! I checked that question previously and I didn't find any information that differs from what I've done. I tried a few of the suggestions (such as setting the BuildConfiguration var), but nothing seemed to help.

I find it very strange that the Azure DevOps Releases log indicates that the transform completed and updated values, but the staging values don't end up in my App Service environment. Also interesting that the App.config contains the staging values, but not the LegendMaintenance.exe.config.

Comment: What's the detail content of LegendMaintenance.exe.Stage.config and LegendMaintenance.exe.config?

Comment: Hi starian chen-MSFT, I edited my post above with the contents of the config files (values censored). These come from the Zip file created during build, and they live in the root directory of the archive with their respective names (LegendMaintenance.exe.Stage.config and LegendMaintenance.exe.Release.config).

Comment: @user949286 ever get a solve for this?

Comment: @smurtagh no, unfortunately not